# Where can I find or make a remote wireless light switch?

Tags: lighting, garage

I have a light switch in my garage that controls lights in front of my home. The switch is located in a corner of the garage where a large shelf has been stored. It is very difficult to the switch.

I'm looking for some sort of wireless receiver/transmitter that I can install to emulate the switch being turned on from inside of the house.

Does anything like this exist?

Comment: Look under the [home-automation](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/home-automation) tag for some questions with information that might help; what's available will depend a lot on where you actually are.

Answer (score 4):

There are plenty of remote switches on the market, especially if your light is (or can be) plugged into a wall socket.

- [X10](http://www.x10.com)  is probably the best-known standard for home automation
- [INSTEON](http://www.insteon.net/) is a backward-compatible extension of X10, introduced in 2005
- [Z-Wave](http://www.homeseer.com/wiki/index.php/ZWave) is a pure-play RF control system
- There are lots of [cheap'n'cheerful generic switches](http://www.geeks.com/details.asp?invtid=BH9936-2&cpc=SCH) available.
- The Zigbee wireless protocol is also starting to get some traction in home automation, after many years as a hobbyist's curiosity, but commercial devices are still rare and expensive.

One thing you should seriously consider, however: security.  X10 devices - and the cheap'n'cheerful stuff - DO NOT encrypt their control signals, so it's scarily possible that criminals might remotely turn off the lights in front of your house for their own purposes.  Unencrypted wireless signals should ONLY be used for stuff where interference or disruption won't cause any damage.

INSTEON, Z-Wave, and Zigbee were all built with security/encryption in mind; I'm sure none of them will make Fort Knox feel insecure, but they should be at least as hard to crack as your garage door opener, anyway.

Comment: Insteon isn't really an extension of X10, it's a completely different protocol.  Most Insteon devices do support the X10 protocol in addition to Insteon for compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

this is easy, just replace the current old fashioned switch that you need to flip up and down with somethign like this that has a manual control as well as a simple remote you can use to tun on/ off the light as well as dim

i got mine at home depot. here is a link to one similar. mine is in my daughters room. she loves it and i am getting one for my master bedroom now.

[home depot link](http://www.homedepot.com/buy/lighting-fans/ceiling-fans-accessories/heath-zenith/wireless-remote-light-setwhite-36076.html?keyword=remote%20light%20switch&langId=-1&storeId=10051&catalogId=10053&omni=)

Answer (score 1):

I know this doesn't answer the remote control question, but would wiring a second switch be an option?  If your garage walls or ceiling are not finished, it might not be too difficult to move the switch to a more convenient location, or convert it to a three way switching circuit with a second switch by the door that goes into the house. That would only require a run of 14/3 and 14/2, two 3-way switches etc.

Answer (score 1):

I used another alternative - replaced the lights with PIR activated units and lend the switch on permanently. This way the lights always turn on as I drive the car up towards the garage.

An added benefit is that we get some extra warning if guests pull in to the drive (or burglars, I guess)

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly this same need, and did -not- want to use outlets or an entire system for just two switches at a place I will probably not be in another year or two. I found what I was looking for at a local HW store recently turned A*E. The brand is ["Heath Zenith"](http://heath-zenith.com), the model is [BL-6133-WH](http://www.heath-zenith.com/servsup_manual.cgi) (the last two letters are the color, in this case White) I believe.

The design is: you replace the original wall switch with a switch that also has an antenna that talks to the "wireless" switch (mounted wherever you want) and the replacement wired wall switch also has a master kill switch on it that will disable the action of both the wired and wireless switches. They are identical from what I can see to a "Chamberlain" branded product that is no longer available on amazon, so I won't bother linking.

Unfortunately, they are quite cheap. Of the two switches, I ended up with two different problems, one is a channel D, and one a channel E. I have not attempted to swap around parts to see what's up… interference could of course be a problem as sometimes the one will not do anything for 19 out of 20 flicks, however it actually seems to be related to poor mechanical design on them both: you can complete the circuit by just tipping the switch about a quarter inch or so, at which point it will just slide back to its original position, unless you keep going to push it over. This of course could be how they are used if one was so inclined, but I like the idea of being able to look at a switch and know what's going on with it (as I'm sure we all do!). The inconsistent one also needs force to be applied toward the wall to work consistently I've figured out… it's ***exactly*** what we were both looking for (you and I) but a bit on the cheap side...

I paid around 30$ each out here in California, and I haven't thought about acting on the 1 year warranty until now… but it seems a design flaw, as, if I remember, the replacement wired switch has the exact same behavior of completing at a quarter inch… yuck! sigh… truthfully, I'm not sure I would get them again… but then thinking about putting my hand in a crack to turn the switches with somebody in my arms and I guess it's better, even though disappointing in some ways.

Check the manual at:
http://www.heath-zenith.com//data/manuals/205259-01A.pdf for some pictures and install plan.